# PyQt4 QPixmap Rotating Jpg according to EXIF

Tags: python, pyqt4, exif, image-rotation

Consider [simple `PyQt4` app, loading picture with `QPixmap`](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/widgets2/) and [scaling with ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9351984/544721).

Crucial part of code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
(...)
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("example.jpg")
pixmap = pixmap.scaled(1100, 1800, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

I've been surprised when I saw my photos in wrong rotation.

I suppose, the reason is that photos contain `EXIF` information about camera position, which should be considered and rotation applied:

```
$ exiftool example.jpg  | grep -i rot
Orientation                     : Rotate 270 CW
Auto Rotate                     : Rotate 270 CW
Rotation                        : 270
```

How to make this with `PyQt4`, staying close to original short form of program... preferably *short&sweet* and *pythonic* way?

Answer (score 4):

You need a way to read and parse the EXIF information. (Py)Qt doesn't have that functionality built-in. But there are nice Python tools out there, like [`pyexiv2`](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/overview.html), [`EXIF.py`](https://github.com/ianare/exif-py), [`PyExifTool`](http://smarnach.github.com/pyexiftool/).

Once you get the rotation angle, then it's easy to apply it to your `QPixmap`:

```
pixmap = pixmap.scaled(1100, 1800, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
pixmap = pixmap.transformed(QtGui.QTransform().rotate(angle))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not most elegant approach, but I've found `exiftool` to be installed on most systems I use, while packages like `pyexiv2` not necessarily.

I used `exiftool`, by using wrapper class proposed at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10075210/544721 (note: in order to use wrapper with Py3k you need to add `.encode()` and `.decode()` in appropriate places for `str<->bytes` conversion)

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('example.jpg')
with ExifTool() as e:
    exif_metadata = e.get_metadata('example.jpg')
    picture_orientation_code = exif_metadata[0]['EXIF:Orientation']
if picture_orientation_code == 8:
    pixmap = pixmap.transformed(QtGui.QTransform().rotate(270))
elif picture_orientation_code == 6:
    pixmap = pixmap.transformed(QtGui.QTransform().rotate(90))
pixmap = pixmap.scaled(1100, 1600, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

Still - I do not consider it as most elegant, but I hope this answer might help other readers until better solution appear.